# Como realizar consulta postgresql en laravel correctamente?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, sql

Hola he tratado de diferentes maneras poder usar una consulta en postgresql para laravel, pero no me funciona, no se como convertirla, la necesito para un controller que estoy haciendo y pdoer generar una tabla en mi blade, esta es la consultaen postgresql:

```
select extract(year from fecha_creacion) as anio, extract(month from fecha_creacion) as mes,
   sum(case when tipo = 'entrada' then 1 else 0 end ) 
 from documento 
group by extract(year from fecha_creacion), extract(month from fecha_creacion)
order by anio, mes;
```

y esta es la consulta en laravel que intento hacer:

```
$data = DB::table('documento')
     ->selectRaw('year from fecha_creacion AS anio, month from fecha_creacion AS mes')
     ->sum(case when tipo = 'entrada' then 1 else 0 end )
    ->orderBy(anio, mes, DESC)
    ->get();
```

Comment: ¿y cuál es el error que obtienes con dicha consulta?

Comment: veo que el `orderBy` te debería dar error, pues los argumentos de dicho método deben ir entre comillas.

Comment: este error me da: syntax error, unexpected 'case' (T_CASE)

Comment: por que no puedes pasar instrucciones SQL directo sin el uso de comillas por dentro de los métodos, por eso el error, te recomendaría revisar la documentación al respecto.